# Why is my Python2 xml parser not working as expected in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xml.etree

The following code is working fine with Python 2.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import json

file_name = 'sample.xml'
full_path = os.path.join('Test', file_name)

tree = ET.parse(full_path)
myroot = tree.getroot()

for test in myroot.findall('bla/blub/test/'):
    print(test.attrib)
    for fw in test:
        print(fw.tag)
        for dn in fw.findall('name'):
            hostname =  dn.text
```

If I try to run the code with Python 3, it won´t use the for loop after:

```
print(fw.tag)
```

print shows that I'm in the correct location:

```
{'name': 'test1'}
etc
name
```

Any ideas, why the code is not working with Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I removed the second for loop.

```
for test in myroot.findall('bla/blub/test/'):
    print(test.attrib)
    for dn in test.findall('name'):
        hostname =  dn.text
```